# Calculating the sample cumulative distribution function for a Kolmogrov-Simulation test to examine the goodness of fit with given data

Tags: self-study, random-variable, simulation, goodness-of-fit, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have sample data for 'Times between successive crashes of a computer system' which is for a 6 month period and the data is given in hours.

The data in brief is : 1,10,20,30,40,52.....

I need to use the Kolmogrov-Smirnov test to examine the goodness of fit for a exponential distribution.
I am given parameter α = 0.00435 , Mean = 1/α = 230 hours.
The total number of data points in the sample is 22.

I'm not sure how to calculate the sample cumulative distribution function (Fs(x)). Currently my approach to it was that each data point should be divided by the sample size(22). As in for data points 1,10,20 the  Fs(x) = 1/22,10/22 etc.

Can I get a confirmation on this approach ?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=empirical+distribution+function.